# div moves other divs when size expands

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm trying to build a row of divs where a div will expand when a mouse hovers over it.
It got that so far but i want that the expanding div is not moving the other divs around (changing there size) but to expand over his neigbours, partly covering them.

i hope you get what i mean..

i also would like to keep the js part because there should happen more stuff when hovering over the elements.

here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
        .wrap{
            font-size: 160px;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 450px;
            width: 1100px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;  
        }
        .a{
            width: 220px;
            height: 350px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
        }
        .b{
            width: 220px;
            height: 350px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
        }
        .c{
            width: 220px;
            height: 350px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
        }
        .d{
            width: 220px;
            height: 350px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
        }
        .e{
            width: 220px;
            height: 350px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        function enlarge(id){
            /*console.log("enlarge: " + id);*/
            var element = document.getElementById(id);
            element.style.height = "440px";
            element.style.width = "260px";
            element.style.borderWidth = "1px";
            element.style.borderStyle = "solid";
            
        }
        function reduce(id){
            /*console.log("reduce: " + id);*/
            var element = document.getElementById(id);
            element.style.height = "350px";
            element.style.width = "220px";
            element.style.borderWidth = "1px";
            element.style.borderStyle = "solid";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <center>
    
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="a" id="a" onmouseover="enlarge(this.id)" onmouseout="reduce(this.id)">A</div>
            <div class="b" id="b" onmouseover="enlarge(this.id)" onmouseout="reduce(this.id)">B</div>
            <div class="c" id="c" onmouseover="enlarge(this.id)" onmouseout="reduce(this.id)">C</div>
            <div class="d" id="d" onmouseover="enlarge(this.id)" onmouseout="reduce(this.id)">D</div>
            <div class="e" id="e" onmouseover="enlarge(this.id)" onmouseout="reduce(this.id)">E</div>
        </div>
    
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

also on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fkdvptuz/

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a wrapper `div` that stores the real size for each, set its position to `relative` then set the position of each expanding `div` to `absolute`.

Something like this:
`html`

```
<center>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="growing-wraper">
      <div class="expanding-el a" id="a" onmouseover="enlarge(this.id)" onmouseout="reduce(this.id)">A</div>
    </div>

    <div class="growing-wraper">
      <div class="expanding-el b" id="b" onmouseover="enlarge(this.id)" onmouseout="reduce(this.id)">B</div>
    </div>

    <div class="growing-wraper">
      <div class="expanding-el c" id="c" onmouseover="enlarge(this.id)" onmouseout="reduce(this.id)">C</div>
    </div>

    <div class="growing-wraper">
      <div class="expanding-el d" id="d" onmouseover="enlarge(this.id)" onmouseout="reduce(this.id)">D</div>
    </div>

    <div class="growing-wraper">
      <div class="expanding-el e" id="e" onmouseover="enlarge(this.id)" onmouseout="reduce(this.id)">E</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
```

```
.wrap {
    font-size: 160px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 450px;
    width: 1100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
  }
  .growing-wraper {
    width: 220px;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .expanding-el {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  .expanding-el:hover {
//This will give an effect of overlap neighbor element
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); 

//This will overlap 
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .a {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
  }

  .b {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
  }

  .c {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
  }

  .d {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
  }

  .e {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
  }
```

Also if you only want to increase the size of the element while hovering, you use `transform:scale(1.5)` CSS properties. You do not need to have a long CSS hassle code.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve behaviour you desire, you need to change particular div's size using CSS's property `translate: scale()` instead of changing width and height directly, you can still keep `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` event handlers for other logic, but scaling will be done using CSS.

Here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/zguajr48/16/) to jsfiddle, I just have added `block` class to every div:

```
.block:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2)
}
```